# How to get the URL of selected hyperlink in android web browser?

Tags: android, url, browser

In my android application I want to get URL of the hyper link text, selected from web page in my android web browser.
How can I get it?

I want to URL of the hyper link (link that is clicked inside of that webview).

please help me..

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand your question at all. Maybe you try to rephrase it a bit.

Comment: I think he wants his application to be able to retrieve the URL a hyperlink points to inside the web browser

Comment: Yes, I want to URL of the hyper link (link that is clicked inside of that web view).

Answer (score 1):

You can add a [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) to your [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). Now you have to extend WebViewClient and override the [shouldOverrideURLloading](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) method. This method will be called every time a URL is loaded.

You now get the URL that is about to load as a String. 
If you want to prevent the WebView from load the URL or jump to another part of your app return true if you want the webview to load the URL return false.

This will only work if you are using a WebView in you application. As far as I know there is no way to hook into the web browser in that way.